# Getting Kochava Attribution false in listener

Tags: android

I am using the Kochava Tracker v3.4.0. I have to get the attribution data from Kochava. But in the `AttributionUpdateListener`, I am getting `{"attribution":"false"}`. My configuration code is:

```
Tracker.configure(new Configuration(application.getApplicationContext())
    .setAppGuid(KOCHAVAGUID)
    .setLogLevel(Tracker.LOG_LEVEL_INFO)
    .setAttributionUpdateListener(attribution -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "attribution: " + attribution);
    })
);
```

I am calling this code in the `Application`'s `onCreate`. How do I get the full attribution data?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the official documentation](https://support.kochava.com/reference-information/attribution-response-examples), the value of {"attribution":"false"} appears to mean that the install was unattributed or "organic."

Comment: What does "install was unattributed or organic" mean?

Comment: organic means that the user installed the app himself  by manually opening  appstore and choosing the app without any advertising